# How can I compare ${HOST} and ${HOST_FROM} (or why ${HOST} != ${HOST})?

Tags: syslog-ng

I have a setup which can be summarized as follow:

```
service --> syslog-ng relay --> syslog-ng server
```

On the `syslog-ng` server, I would have the log organized as follow:

```
/var/log/ ----> syslog-ng server local log files...
           \--> ${FROM_HOST}/ 
                 \---> Syslog-ng relay host log files...
                 \---> ${HOST}/
                        \---> Service log files...
```

- Logs generated locally on the `syslog-ng` server located in their default location, */var/log*.
- Logs generated on a relay in a subdirectory bearing the relay name, */var/log/${FROM_HOST}*.
- Logs generated by a service in a subdirectory of its associated relay, */var/log/${FROM_HOST}/${HOST}*

I created the following configuration on the `syslog-ng` server host:

```
@version: 3.7
@include "scl.conf"

options {
    dns-cache-hosts("/etc/hosts");
    keep-hostname(yes);
    use-dns(persist_only);
};

...(removed)...

# syslog-ng server local logs, works fine.
log {
    source(local_src);
    local_file();
};

# syslog-ng relays, never matches.
log {
    source(remote_src);
    filter { host("${HOST_FROM}", type(string)); };
    local_file(subdir("${HOST_FROM}/"));
};

# Services, works fine but also matches syslog-ng relays.
log {
    source(remote_src);
    filter { not host("${HOST_FROM}", type(string)); };
    local_file(subdir("${HOST_FROM}/$(sanitize $HOST)/"));
};
```

For information `local_file()` is a custom log block taking as parameter the subdirectory where to store logs entries.

The [`host()`](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-filters.html#filter-host) filter is described as comparing its parameter with *${HOST}*. My idea was there to use this to check *${HOST}* (the author of the syslog message) and *${HOST_FROM}* (the last hop of the syslog message):

- If they are equal, the message has been generated by the `syslog-ng` relay.
- If they are different, the message has been generated by a service.

However, the test `host("${HOST_FROM}", type(string))` always fails, even though the generated path does not show any difference between the values of *${HOST}* and *${HOST_FROM}* (for instance, given a relay named *therelay*, relays logs will be stored below */var/log/therelay/therelay/* (expansion of */var/log/${HOST_FROM}/$(sanitize $HOST)/*).

I tried to remove sanitization, to interpret the pattern as a regexp instead of a raw string, add `.*` at the beginning and the end of the pattern while a regexp, remade all these tests while replacing `host("${HOST_FROM}")` by `match("${HOST_FROM}", value(HOST))`, but nothing seems to work.

Actually, even `host("${HOST}")` (comparing *${HOST}* with itself) seems to never match.

Replacing the filter with `filter { host(".*"); };` however correctly forces this entry to match.

Is this the expected behavior? How can I compare the content of *${HOST}* and *${HOST_FROM}*?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer so I leave my question open for now.

It seems that macros are not expanded in filter functions, most likely due a speed optimization as the use of a ["somewhat slower"](https://www.balabit.com/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/filters-comparing.html) specific syntax seems required in such case.

`host("${HOST_FROM}")` will only match against a host literally named *${HOST_FROM}*, which is not likely to happen under normal circumstances.

The right test to do seems to be the filter defined below:

```
filter { "${HOST}" == "${HOST_FROM}" };
```

While this syntax may be less efficient, I think this is only way to compare the content of two macros.